# Vietnamese Unicode characters string error (showing "?")

Tags: excel, vba, string, unicode

I am using Excel VBA, I have an error when I assign Vietnamese-Unicode character values in variable or `MsgBox`, like this:

```
Range("A1").Value = "Nguyễn Văn Bình"
MsgBox(Sheet5.Range("a453").Value
```

It results with: `Nguy?n V?n B?nh`

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Typically, the `?` means that the OS doesn't support that character.  Do these characters display correctly in the code before you run the sub?  For example, if I copy the string to my editor I immediately get question marks because I don't have this font loaded on my machine;

Comment: Avoid using MsgBox(), it came from the previous century and pretends that Unicode doesn't exist.  Otherwise a bit odd to have your operating system's default code page configured wrong like that.  Might be a specific Vietnamese problem, I'm guessing that [this page](http://www.bluesofts.net/Baiviet/Laptrinh/VB_VBA/MsgBoxUnicode.htm) is more readable to me than to you.  The bad encoding in the web page is not encouraging :)

Comment: A try In Control Panel > Regional and language options> advanced tab to choose the native language you want to use for non-unicode programs, maybe helps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I display a messagebox with unicode characters in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55210315/how-do-i-display-a-messagebox-with-unicode-characters-in-vba)