# How to display umlauts with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-project

I'm writing a macro in MS Project. In a form I'm using Date and Time Picker control. And I have to use German locale. 
The problem is in the point that VBA doesn't display umlauts correct and *März* looks like *Mдrz* in the Calendar.

I have problem with MsgBox too. Special symbols *ü*, *ö*, *ä*, *ß* are displayed like *ь*, *ц*, *д*, *Я* in message. I’ve tried to use the `CharW()? function to display Unicode symbols, and symbols displays like *o*, *u*, *a*?

I set de-DE locale in MS Project and German locale on my computer, but it did not help.

Is it possible to explicitly use utf-8 encoding in VBA?

Comment: Linked question: [ms access - How do I display a messagebox with unicode characters in VBA? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55210315/how-do-i-display-a-messagebox-with-unicode-characters-in-vba) although that one does not handle characters in form labels.

Answer (score 0):

Try **not to** display the `ä` in the VBA code. It really looks bad and it is a bad practice to have anything but the standard latin characters there. The strings could stay in a database/excel sheet and could be accessed from there, which is the good practice.

Anyway, for the bad practice:

ä -    `ChrW(&H00E4)`

The rest is available here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Comment: This is an interesting article for Unicode - https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: thank you for your answer. Unfortunately bad practice doesn't work too, _ä_ looks like _a_ in message. And I still need to do something with _Mдrz_ in Calendar, because I can't change system name of month.

Comment: @Shalaieva - for a messagebox, you cannot do it, but you would be able to write it somewhere in the app, which uses a string. See a bit more here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55210315/how-do-i-display-a-messagebox-with-unicode-characters-in-vba