# how to get msgbox text from reference cell, which includes newline characters

Tags: excel, vba

edit: all responses have missed my point, so i've removed any mention of special characters and just want to focus on the line break `vbCrLf`

i have a combobox populated from a range of cells, and i want a msgbox to pop up based on the user's selection in said combobox, such that the msgbox text is taken from a cell which corresponds to the user's selected cell (i.e. the cell linked to the user's cbox selection). for example:

| user selection | msgbox text |
| --- | --- |
| scarf | It's 40 degrees. Are you sure you want a scarf? |
| swimshorts | Don't forget your sunscreen! |

so that's the reason for trying to fill the cbox from a cell, rather than from VB.

my problem is how to write the **newline** <s>and special character</s> in the reference cell and have msgbox format it correctly.

i.e. `MsgBox "It's 40 degrees." & vbCrLf & "Are you sure you want a scarf?"` does what i want, but if i place that text in a cell and then try to reference that cell with a msgbox, e.g. `MsgBox Sheet1.Range("B2")`, then the msgbox just prints the text without formatting.

e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9hVH.jpg

please, any help here would be greatly appreciated

Comment: thanks, braX. i tried that, but the msgbox still displayed the string as written without any formatting, i.e. "It's 40" & ChrW(8451) & vbCrLf & "Are you sure you want a scarf?"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55210315/how-do-i-display-a-messagebox-with-unicode-characters-in-vba

Comment: that's different. if i directly call `MsgBox ChrW(8451)`, i get the degree C symbol, but if i put `ChrW(8451)` in, say, cell `A1`, and then `MsgBox [A1]`, my messagebox comes up with "ChrW(8451)"

Comment: @MikeRotch try the answer that braX posted, remember to change to `Application.hWnd` as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: In Excel, the function to return unicode characters from their "number" is `UNICHAR`.  But `MSGBOX` is not compatible with those characters so you need a different solution.

Comment: @MikeRotch *"if i directly call MsgBox ChrW(8451), i get the degree C symbol*  What version of Excel?  If I do that (from the immediate window in the VBA editor), I get the `?`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Excel2019... but the special characters weren't really the problem. i have since edited my post (and in the meanwhile, i see that you have already answered it). just out of curiosity, what about `MsgBox ChrW(176)` ? i only ask because it seems i may need to consider the characters available to other users, seeing as `ChrW(8451)` didn't work for you

Comment: Not at computer, but you can check it easily enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a line feed in a cell, if you are entering it from the worksheet:

```
A1: ="abc" & CHAR(10) & "def"
```

For the `linefeed` character, you can type `abc`<kbd>alt+enter</kbd>`def`

[image]

If you are entering it from VBA, then the code line would be:

```
Range("A1")  = "abc" & vblf & "def"
```

Comment: my sincerest thanks, entering `="abc" & CHAR(10) & "def"` in the worksheet cell worked perfectly, while `abc` `alt+010` `def` did not work for me either.

on the other hand, `abc` `Alt+Enter` `def` (no `=` or `"`) also worked perfectly.

*edited because <kbd> tags don't work in comments

Comment: ps. sorry i don't have enough reputation to upvote

Comment: @MikeRotch See my edit for entering the linefeed character from the keyboard -- brain cramp last night.  It's `alt-enter`, not `alt-0010`