# Excel VBA Unicode Character not Displaying Correctly in Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to display in a string the Calibri symbol of a circle with a 1 in the middle ① (U+2460).  Searching through the forum this should work ChrW$(&H2460), but doesn't. It generates a question mark in the text string.   Removing the dollar sigh or ampersand sign also doesn't work.

```
Dim Prior_Char As String
Dim Output_String  As String

Prior_Char = ChrW$(&H2460)
Output_String = "Occurrence Count" & Prior_Char
```

Why the question mark and not ① ?

Comment: What are you doing with `Output_String` ?. `Cells(1, 1) = Output_String` displays correctly on the sheet for me.

Comment: You're not trying to view the string in the Immediate Window / VBE are you?

Comment: `MsgBox Output_String` <= this fails for me ...
`Cells(1, 1) = Output_String` <= this works ...

Comment: I am trying to then print 'Output_String' to a text file with:

Print #1, Output_String

So what is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this post: [MsgBox with Unicode Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55210315/how-do-i-display-a-messagebox-with-unicode-characters-in-vba)
you can define an alternative function to display Unicode characters.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function MessageBoxW Lib "User32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpText As LongPtr, ByVal lpCaption As LongPtr, ByVal uType As Long) As Long

Public Function MsgBoxW(Prompt As String, Optional Buttons As VbMsgBoxStyle = vbOKOnly, Optional Title As String = "Microsoft Excel") As VbMsgBoxResult
    MsgBoxW = MessageBoxW(Application.hWnd, StrPtr(Prompt), StrPtr(Title), Buttons)
End Function

Sub TestMsgBoxW()
   Dim s As String
   s = ChrW(&H2460)
   MsgBoxW s
End Sub
```