Reading UTF-8 texts in PowerPoint via VBA, for export to another software
I want to read all text in a PowerPoint file using VBA, and write them to external file (or some other way) to use in another Software.
I wrote this code:
Sub ReadFileText()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim shp As Shape
    
    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
             If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                MsgBox shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                ' if text was read successfully, I can save it to a text or json file.
             End If
        Next shp
    Next sld
End Sub

Some shapes includes non-ASCII (UTF-8) characters in text.
VBA returns them as "?" character!
How can I read shape text as UTF-8 string?


Pls share a screenshot of the shape. What's the next step after retrieving the text?

@taller I don't know how can I insert images here! But I uploaded the screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/S54IHDa

Pls share a screenshot of shapes/slide instead of popup message box. Click the [Edit] button located below the tags to upload an image.

You cannot properly display UTF-8 text using MsgBox (or Debug.Print) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55210315/how-do-i-display-a-messagebox-with-unicode-characters-in-vba   The accepted answer at the linked post shows how to work around that.

@TimWilliams want to read from slides, so I can't user ChrW()

@taller I add as way to said, bot again it's a link in the question!

"read from slides" means what exactly though?  Are you just displaying in a messagebox the text you already can see on the slide?

I've asked the same question in the first comment as @Tim. What's the next step after retrieving the text?

You are using "UTF-8" to mean "Unicode". They are not the same. The solution you have been advised is about declaring MessageBoxW, not about using ChrW, so you can use it.

I fixed the question: I want to export data to another software.

@GSerg It's not same to the question that you marked as duplicated, I clarify the question, and accept the correct answer.

PowerPoint/VBA can work internally with UTF-8 but as Tim mentions, can't display UTF-8 text in message boxes/debug window.
But when I add some Japanese text to a slide, then do
Activewindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Copy
I can then paste into a notepad UTF-8 file and get the correct text.
What you get may vary depending on what you DO with the copied text.

You are using "UTF-8" to mean "Unicode". They are not the same. PowerPoint/VBA not just "can" work internally with Unicode strings, it has and does. All strings in VBA are Unicode, there are no non-Unicode strings.



PowerPoint/VBA not just "can" work internally with Unicode strings, it has and does. All strings in VBA are Unicode
Internally, yes. But not in messageboxes/debug.print and possibly other places. Try debugging code that returns e.g. Simplified Chinese text. Without playing games with Windows language settings, all you get is square boxes or ???



Instead of using the MsgBox, create a simple UserForm with the Label. The Label allows configuring text properties, so you can choose an appropriate font that will display the characters properly.
